# Sending sms with textLocal Api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, nodejs-server, textlocal

I am getting the response:

> **response  {   errors: [ { code: 80, message: 'Invalid template' } ],   status: 'failure' }**

Template status is Active and
Template I have registered with my Textlocal account:

> Welcome to %%|applicationName^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" :
> "20"}%%, Your OTP is %%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" :
> "6"}%%.Thanks Doosy

- How should I send a message with this template? My current code is:

> 

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiKey = "Api" 
const sender = "Dooosy"
const number = "91**********"
let applicationName = "application name"
let otp = "123123"
const message = encodeURIComponent(`Welcome to ${applicationName}, Your OTP is ${otp}. Thanks Doosy`);

var url = "http://api.textlocal.in/send/?" + 'apiKey=' + apiKey + '&sender=' + sender + '&numbers=' + number + '&message=' + message

const sendSms = async (req, res) => {
    axios
        .post(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("response ", response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error ", error.message);
        });
}

export default sendSms
```

I use this sendSms file in my other file like this

```
import sendSms from './sendSms.js'

app.get("/demo") => { 
        sendSms()  // called this function for send sms
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "otp sent successfully"
        })

 }
```

Comment: it's problem with your text local template